# Kohana 3.2 not working Form helper

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3.2

I have some code, where is used Form helper. All worked well. Now I have error

```
Call to undefined method Form::open()
```

When I check `SYSPATH` exist `classes` `Form` and `Kohana_Form`

This situation is in each file where is used this helper.

This is `kohana 3.2`. In this files was not any changes. I tried it on `PHP 5.4` and `PHP 5.5`

Any idea why? Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: The same situation is with every element from Form helper.

I trough that reason is using git to download kohana core and modules, but it not work also on server where was upload full code without use git.

Comment: Are you in a namespace when you're trying to call it?

Comment: No I don't use namespaces in this project. It's not my project. It worked in past (1 week ago). Now I see that problem is with `Form` class. Because `Kohana_Form` works well. But I can't change it, to many views to change.

Comment: Do you have a `Form.php` in `application_public/helpers` (or whatever your application folder is)? If so, this overrides `Kohana_Form`, and if it doesn't extend `Kohana_Form` it'll bork out there

Comment: In my application folder are only controllers and models. Any file have not Form.php name.

Comment: You should have in your system folder file named form.php with class Form extends Kohana_Form {}, in system/kohana you should also have form.php with class Kohana_Form and static method open(). If something is missing then someone deleted/changed it. If it exist and is in same format as I wrote, then double confirm your SYSPATH variable if for sure it is using this system folder that you are checking

Answer (score 0):

The most likely thing is that you have a Form.php somewhere that's overriding the SYSTEM Form.php. To find out if this is happening, use the Kohana::find_file() function like this:

```
Kohana::find_file('classes', 'form');
```

The output from this should tell you the path of the Form.php that's being used when you call the Form class. Check if it's the one in the SYSTEM folder.